# Thymeleaf 3 - Data-th-text cannot contains "Not" - Could not parse as expression: "Not" exception

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a simple select form with three options. I want one of the to be "**Not mounted**"
The problem is that I cannot set "Not"  in data-th-textbecause it is recognized as an expression.

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="status">Status:</label>
                    <select data-th-field="*{status}" id="status" class="form-control">
                        <option data-th-value="available" data-th-text="Available"></option>
                        <option data-th-value="broken" data-th-text="Broken"></option>
                        <option data-th-value="not mounted" data-th-text="Not Mounted" ></option>
                    </select>
</div>
```

I receive an expesion

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "Not" (template: "exhibitor/editExhibitor" - line 20, col 60)
```

How can I show the "Not Mounted" text ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `data-th-text`, then thymeleaf is expecting an expression that can be evaluated.  You have 2 options here:

Use regular attributes.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="status">Status:</label>

    <select data-th-field="*{status}" id="status" class="form-control">
        <option value="available">Available</option>
        <option value="broken">Broken</option>
        <option value="not mounted">Not Mounted</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Make your attributes valid thymeleaf expressions.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="status">Status:</label>
    <select data-th-field="*{status}" id="status" class="form-control">
        <option data-th-value="'available'" data-th-text="'Available'"></option>
        <option data-th-value="'broken'" data-th-text="'Broken'"></option>
        <option data-th-value="'not mounted'" data-th-text="'Not Mounted'" ></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="status">Status:</label>
    <select data-th-field="*{status}" id="status" class="form-control">
        <option data-th-value="${'available'}" data-th-text="${'Available'}"></option>
        <option data-th-value="${'broken'}" data-th-text="${'Broken'}"></option>
        <option data-th-value="${'not mounted'}" data-th-text="${'Not Mounted'}" ></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can make sure that Thymeleaf understands it's a string by using
   single quotes:

   `data-th-text="'Not Mounted'"`
2. Or even better, make it internationalized and get it from a message bundle:

   `data-th-text="#{notMounted}"`

   In your `messages.properties`:

   `notMounted=Not Mounted`

   but then this could alternatively be:

   `<option th:text="#{notMounted}" value="not mounted">Not Mounted</option>`

Just note that whichever option you chose, you'll want to escape any single-quotes within your string with a backslash `\`.